# An exercise on the calculation of some Fréchet derivatives.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, frechet-derivative

The following is Exercise VII.5.15.(iii) from *Analysis II* by Amann & Escher.

> Suppose $X$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^m$. For $f,g\in C^1(X,\mathbb{R}^m)$, define $[f,g]\in C(X,\mathbb{R}^m)$ by $$[f,g](x):=\partial f(x)g(x)−\partial g(x)f(x)$$ for $x\in X$. We call $[f,g]$ the **Lie bracket** of $f$ and $g$.
>
> (iii) $[\varphi f,\psi g]=\varphi\psi[f,g]+(\nabla\varphi|f)\psi f−(\nabla\psi|g)\varphi g$ for $\varphi,\psi\in C^1(X,\mathbb{R})$.

After some routine calculations I got $$[\varphi f,\psi g]=\varphi\psi[f,g]+(\nabla\varphi|g)\psi f−(\nabla\psi|f)\varphi g.$$ Am I wrong or is this a typo?

Given that the calculations are routine and a bit tedious, I will not include my attempt here... I hope this doesn't make the question ill-posed.

Comment: whats $\nabla \phi | g$?

Comment: @mathworker21 That's the Euclidean inner product, usually denoted by $a\cdot b$. If you plug in $x$ it's  $[\varphi f,\psi g](x)=\varphi(x)\psi(x)[f,g](x)+(\nabla\varphi(x)|g(x))\psi(x)f(x)−(\nabla\psi(x)|f(x))\varphi(x)g(x).$